# cannot partition this mysql table

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-partitioning

I have an innoDB table named "transaction" with ~1.5 million rows. I would like to partition this table (probably on column "gas_station_id" since it is used a lot in join queries) but I've read in [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html) that

> All columns used in the table's partitioning expression must be part of every unique key that the table may have, including any primary key.

I have two questions:

1. The column "gas_station_id" is not part of unique key or primary key. How could I partition this table then?
2. even if I could partition this table, I am not sure which partitioning type would be better in this case? (I was thinking about LIST partitioning (we have about 40 different(distinct) gas stations) but I am not sure since there will be only one value in each list partition like the following :
   `ALTER TABLE transaction 
   PARTITION BY LIST(gas_station_id) 
   ( PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (9001), 
   PARTITION p2 VALUES IN (9002),.....`)
3. I tried partitioning by `KEY`, but I receive the following error (I think because id is not part of all unique keys..):

> #1053 - a UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

This is the structure of the "transaction" table:

[image]

**EDIT**
and this is what SHOW CREATE TABLE shows:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `terminal_transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_terminal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_terminal_serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `xboard_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `gas_station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `operator_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 `shift_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `xboard_total_counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `start_fuel_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `end_fuel_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `preset_amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `actual_amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fuel_cost` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `payment_cost` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `purchase_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_ref_id` text,
 `unit_fuel_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fuel_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fuel_mode_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `payment_result` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `card_pan` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `totalizer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `shift_start_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `terminal_transaction_id` (`terminal_transaction_id`,`fuel_terminal_id`,`start_fuel_time`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `start_fuel_time_idx` (`start_fuel_time`),
 KEY `fuel_terminal_idx` (`fuel_terminal_id`),
 KEY `xboard_idx` (`xboard_id`),
 KEY `gas_station_id` (`gas_station_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `purchase_type` (`purchase_type`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `shift_start_time` (`shift_start_time`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `fuel_type` (`fuel_type`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1665335 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Comment: If that table has a billion rows, beware.  `id INT SIGNED` is limited to about 2 billion.

Comment: Many of those `INTs` don't need to be a full 4 bytes; shrink them to space space, thereby improve cacheability, hence better speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  Don't use PARTITION.  Let's see the query to help speed it up.

Long answer:

- 1.5M rows is only marginally big enough to consider partitioning.
- PARTITION BY LIST is probably useless for performance.
- You have not given enough info to give you answers other that vague hints.  Please provide at least `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the slow `SELECT`.
- It is possible to add the partition key onto the end of the `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key; you will lose the uniqueness test.
- Don't index a low-cardinality column; it won't be used.

[*More on PARTITION*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/)

Comment: Thanks Rick for your help. I edited my question and added `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Actually at the moment the transaction table has 1.5M rows. We will have similar table with much more records (around 1 billion rows). I increased the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and now queries are much faster, but I am not sure whether changing this variable alone would be enough for the bigger table that we will have in the near future. that is why I was thinking about partitioning this table.

Comment: The buffer_pool is an important factor in performance; it should be about 70% of available RAM.

Comment: Can't judge whether a query will run faster without seeing the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Right now all queries are fast (just by increasing the buffer_pool). Do you think even if this table had 1 billion rows, we may not need partitioning only with increasing the buffer_pool (I increased it to ~70% of available RAM, i.e., 16G)

Comment: Partitioning does not intrinsically provide any speedup.  See my link for the only 4 use cases where partitioning helps.